# The Indefinite pronoun in Genitiv

Tags: sentence-structure

> Einige Leute mögen solche Lösungen lieber nicht.
>   Rund 40 solcher Center beschäftigen 15000 Leute.

"solcher" in the 2. sentence is Genitiv; how could we identify The Indefinite pronoun in Genitiv?

Answer (score 4):

> Rund 40 solcher Center beschäftigen 15000 Leute.

*Solcher/solche/solches* is a demonstrative pronoun. As this is clearly plural, the indefinite article *ein* does not match. But *einige* does:

> **Einige** solcher Center beschäftigen 15000 Leute.

*Keiner/keine/keines* is also an indefinite determiner, but it commands the singular:

> **Keines** dieser Center beschäftigt 15000 Leute.

(You should not use *solcher/solche/solches* with *keiner/keine/keines*.)

---

Oh, and using *Center* means *I talk Denglish, bow to me!* There is an existing word for this, *das Zentrum, die Zentren*, which had been imported a while ago and got through the proper Germanification already. Use it.

Comment: thanks indeed ... so "Rund 40 solcher Center" means here "around 40 of such centers" that is why Genitive

Answer (score 3):

The use of indefinite pronouns varies from pronoun to pronoun. If your goal is to figure out the case as part of a translation, I would suggest to look for clues from other declined words, e.g. the noun or adjectives.

But let's investigate your example to illustrate this a little bit:
*solch-* can appear both declined or not declined.
If *solch-* is declined, the same rules as for *gemischte Deklination* (eng.: *mixed declension*?) of an adjective apply. I.e. in plural you would use the same endings as for the *starke Deklination* (*strong declension*). In singular, *solch-* would get the endings for *schwache Deklination (*weak declension*), together with *ein-*.
E.g.:

#### plural

> solch**er** Männer/Frauen/Häuser

#### singular:

> *(eines)* solch**en** *Mannes*
>
> *(einer)* solch**en** *Frau*
>
> *(eines)* solch**en** *Hauses*

For complete tables see e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension#Adjectives

### No declension

You might also encounter the use of *solch* with no ending. In that case, the following adjective (if any) is strongly declined and can help you with the case:

> Solch schöner Männer/Frauen/Häuser
>
> solch schön*en* Mannes
>
> solch schön*er* Frau
>
> solch schön*en* Hauses

Main source:

Der kleine Duden Deutsche Grammatik